# multi thread issue in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

New to Python multi-thread and write such simple program, here is my code and error message, any ideas what is wrong? Thanks.

Using Python 2.7.

```
import time
import thread

def uploader(threadName):

    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        print threadName

if __name__ == "__main__":

    numOfThreads = 5
    try:
        i = 0
        while i < numOfThreads:
            thread.start_new_thread(uploader, ('thread'+str(i)))
            i += 1

        print 'press any key to exit test'
        n=raw_input()

    except:
       print "Error: unable to start thread"

Unhandled exception in thread started by <pydev_monkey._NewThreadStartupWithTrace instance at 0x10e12c830>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_monkey.py", line 521, in __call__
    return self.original_func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: uploader() takes exactly 1 argument (7 given)
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: `('thread'+str(i))` will give you a string, not a tuple. Try this: `('thread'+str(i),)`.

Comment: @JustinBarber, thanks for the response and vote up. I met with the same error, this is the line of code I am using after your advice `thread.start_new_thread(uploader, ('thread'+str(i),))`, if anything wrong, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: You mean you get this error: `uploader() takes exactly 1 argument (7 given)`? Are you sure you have saved it before re-running it? Incidentally, if you are new to python, you might find the [threading module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html) more helpful.

Comment: @JustinBarber, yes, it seems have file save issue. And your solution works for me. Could you add an answer? I will mark it as an answer and benefit other people.

Comment: It seems to work for me when I change the line as @JustinBarber suggested. The threads start printing their names after sleeping for 5 secs.

Comment: @Lin Ma I have added the answer below. Glad you figured it out. Cheers.

Comment: @jDo, yes, it is my file save issue. Justin's code works for me. :)

Comment: @LinMa Good to hear :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The args of `thread.start_new_thread` [need to be a tuple](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/thread.html#thread.start_new_thread). Instead of this:

```
('thread' + str(i))  # results in a string
```

Try this for the args:

```
('thread' + str(i),)  # a tuple with a single element
```

Incidentally, you should check out the [`threading` module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html), which is a higher-level interface than `thread`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Justin. Mark your reply as an answer. :)

Comment: Thanks, @Lin Ma! Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

In the following, threadName is now a global variable defined towards the top of the program code, then the variable is initialized before the new thread is started with the target being the upload function.

Try this:

```
import time
import thread

threadName = ''

def uploader():

    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        print threadName

if __name__ == "__main__":

    numOfThreads = 5
    try:
        i = 0
        while i < numOfThreads:
            threadName = 'thread' + str(i)
            newThread = threading.Thread(target=uploader)
            newThread.start()
            i += 1

        print 'press any key to exit test'
        n=raw_input()

    except:
       print "Error: unable to start thread"
```

Comment: Code only answers, although they may be part of a complete answer, are discouraged since they do not explain what was fixed or how.

For people with similar issues in the future, this may not help them resolve their own questions without asking a subsequent question.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Ok I will keep that in mind when answering.  I just edited the answer with a quick explanation